# How do I send an email with Amazon SES in Swift?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk

I am trying to send an email with Amazon SES. I get no errors when I run this, but nothing happens. I've tried to find documentation, but Amazon is quite bad at this. So, any ideas? EDIT: I've verified the mail that I'm trying to send from in the Amazon SES console as well.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    let sns = AWSSES.defaultSES()

    var messageBody = AWSSESContent()
    var subject = AWSSESContent()
    var body = AWSSESBody()
    subject.data = "Subject"
    messageBody.data = "Message body"
    body.text = messageBody

    var message = AWSSESMessage()
    message.subject = subject
    message.body = body

    var destination = AWSSESDestination()
    destination.toAddresses = ["emailadress@gmail.com"]

    var send = AWSSESSendEmailRequest()
    send.source = "emailadress@gmail.com"
    send.destination = destination
    send.message = message


    sns.sendEmail(send).continueWithSuccessBlock {(task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
        NSLog("Sent mail - success")
        return nil
    }


}
```

Comment: Post any specific errors you're getting

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem was that I wasn't using the right region for the SES service. Working code:

```
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
            CognitoRegionType,
            identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
            region: SESServiceRegionType,
            credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
        var sns = AWSSES(configuration: configuration)

        var messageBody = AWSSESContent()
        var subject = AWSSESContent()
        var body = AWSSESBody()
        subject.data = "Subject"
        messageBody.data = "Message body"
        body.text = messageBody

        var theMessage = AWSSESMessage()
        theMessage.subject = subject
        theMessage.body = body

        var destination = AWSSESDestination()
        destination.toAddresses = ["emailadress@gmail.com"]

        var send = AWSSESSendEmailRequest()
        send.source = "emailadress@gmail.com"
        send.destination = destination
        send.message = theMessage
        send.returnPath = "emailadress@gmail.com"

        sns.sendEmail(send).continueWithBlock {(task: AnyObject!) -> BFTask! in

            return nil
        }
```